# Difference between element(...) and element(...).getWebElement() in Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

- Why we need `element(...).getWebElement()` over `element(...)` when both works exactly the same
- Why two APIs for the same functionality

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Protractor` is a convenient wrapper around `WebDriverJS` - javascript selenium bindings.

- `element(...)` would result into an [`ElementFinder` instance](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder) introduced in Protractor
- [`element(...).getWebElement()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.getWebElement) would result into a `WebElement` instance from `WebDriverJS`. Basically, this gives you access to the pure "bare-metal" `WebElement`.

---

The most common use-case for using `getWebElement()` is when you need to pass an `ElementFinder` as a *script argument* - currently you have to call `getWebElement()` for this to work:

```
var elm = element(by.id("myid")); 
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", elm.getWebElement());
```

There is an [open feature-request to be able to pass `ElementFinder` directly](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1600):

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", elm);  // not gonna work as of now
```