# "browser.findElements" works, but "element.all" doesn't

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I am testing a form in Angular 9, and I want to check if any error messages are displayed using Protractor 5.4.3. Error messages are shown according to an *ngIf.

Outside the test, the code works normally.

If I do the search as the [official documentation](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.all) recommends, there is no element:

```js
const elements = await element.all(by.css('.my-class')).getWebElements();
```

But if I do it this way, the result is returned correctly:

```js
const elements = await browser.findElements(by.css('.my-class'));
```

Although my test works using the second solution, I would like to understand what the difference is between the two, and what I'm doing wrong so the first way doesn't work. Could anyone explain? Thanks.

Ps: As I understand it, the two forms would be equivalent, because according to [official documentation](https://www.protractortest.org/#/webdriver-vs-protractor), it would be just syntactic sugar. But there is obviously some difference between them, since only one works for me, or else it is a bug.

Comment: what does just element.all show?

Comment: An empty array []

Comment: Is there a reason you want the base webelement object from webdriverJs as opposed to the element finder? ([See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39026997/difference-between-element-and-element-getwebelement-in-protractor)). Also I don't see any reference to the method `getWebElements` plural. Can you indicate where you learned of that method?

Comment: "await element.all(by.css('.my-class'))" also returns an empty array, with .count() == 0, I used .getWebElements() to both return the same result type. This method is suggested by intellisense, is on [this link](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) and in articles on the web.